# Right way to form an JSON file over iteration

Tags: python, json

I need to write a couple of URLs into a JSON file. 
This is what I have done so far;

```
 for index, document in enumerate(master_data):

            # create a dictionary for each document in the master list
            document_dict = {}
            document_dict['cik_number'] = document[0]
            document_dict['company_name'] = document[1]
            document_dict['form_id'] = document[2]
            document_dict['date'] = document[3]
            document_dict['file_url'] = document[4]

            master_data[index] = document_dict

 for document_dict in master_data:

        # if it's a 10-K document pull the url and the name.
        if document_dict['form_id'] == '10-K':

            # get the components
            data = {}
            data['company name'] = document_dict['company_name']
            data['cik_number'] = document_dict['cik_number']
            data['form_id'] = document_dict['form_id']
            data['date'] = document_dict['date']
            data['file_url'] = document_dict['file_url']

            write(data, JSON_file_to_write)
            JSON_file_to_write.write('\n')
```

And this is what I get at the end;

```
{"company name": "ZERO CORP", "cik_number": "109284", "form_id": "10-K", "date": "19940629", "file_url": "https://www.sec.gov/Archives/data/109284/0000898430-94-000468.txt"}
{"company name": "FOREST LABORATORIES INC", "cik_number": "109563", "form_id": "10-K", "date": "19940628", "file_url": "https://www.sec.gov/Archives/data/38074/0000038074-94-000021.txt"}
{"company name": "GOULDS PUMPS INC", "cik_number": "14637", "form_id": "10-K", "date": "19940331", "file_url": "https://www.sec.gov/Archives/data/42791/0000042791-94-000002.txt"}
{"company name": "GENERAL HOST CORP", "cik_number": "275605", "form_id": "10-Q", "date": "19940701", "file_url": "https://www.sec.gov/Archives/data/40638/0000950124-94-001209.txt"}
```

But as my understanding, I have created a text file containing JSON files. 
But I need to create a single JSON file so that I can iterate over those file_url's and download them into a folder.

I am really really new into Python and JSON and coding actually, and I'm kind of trying to get done assignment for my Capstone project, so please don't be harsh if I asked my question in the wrong format and please show me the right way so I can learn and have better communication with everyone in this portal.

Comment: In your sample, you have created 4 individual dictionaries. You should put those 4 dictionaries in a list. Then convert it to a JSON string, then write that string to a file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to append it to a list instead of writing immediately to the file. Then you convert your list of dicts to a JSON object and write that to the file.

```
import json

jsonList = []
for document_dict in master_data:

    # if it's a 10-K document pull the url and the name.
    if document_dict['form_id'] == '10-K':
        # get the components
        data = {}
        data['company name'] = document_dict['company_name']
        data['cik_number'] = document_dict['cik_number']
        data['form_id'] = document_dict['form_id']
        data['date'] = document_dict['date']
        data['file_url'] = document_dict['file_url']
        jsonList.append(data)

with open('filename.txt', 'w') as the_file: #change w to a if you want to append
    the_file.write(json.dumps(jsonList))
```

Comment: thanks a lot ! Do you think that the way I asked my question was okay ? or should I try to simplify it more ? I'm want to be professional in asking questions :)

Comment: In my opinion it was good. Explained your point. Had correct tags. Posted your output. Most people would want to see the expected output but it wasn't hard to figure out from what you posted.